# What control can display multicolumn data simply

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-columns

I want to display data in one control Vertically with a window form control in C#, such as:

```
Title:       The Game
Name:        Andrew Smith
Age:         44
ISBN:        123456123456
Costs:       £39.99
```

I'm looking for a simple display with code to add and remove items..
I have a list of data which I want to display quite simply from a list which will be displayed as Title/Item as above, which won't need to be amended only viewed.

Is there a way to find out the dimensions of the text and create padding, or is there an automatically adjusting multiple column type control? Any thing with some code to stop me going mad regarding special list Views and grid type views.

Comment: Yes, I'll amend the q

Comment: I found this http://www.csharpcity.com/2010/multi-column-listview-controls/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DataGridView. It is simple to use.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I want to avoid using a database. I'm looking for easy installation and use of XML files.  Is there a control that could display how I want but not use a database

Comment: For the record, you do not need a database, or even a DataTable to use the DataGridView. A simple List<T> can be attached to a binding source and used as the data.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned List Views in your post, and I think that is the answer for you. Try a `ListView` control with `View` set to `Details`. Use the Designer to create a column for each field in your data, and then use `listView1.Items.Add()` to add each item. (There is a constructor for `ListViewItem` which takes an array of strings; the strings are the values for each column.)

Comment: Details is used for Horizontal Columns, but I'm looking for Vertical.  Do you know how to display vertically?

Comment: @user3200163 I see; in that case I agree with Ali's answer below (DataGridView). Or, you can simply disable `AutoSize` on the labels, make them all the same size, and set the text alignment to `RightCenter`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **BookItem** class which has properties shown below.

```
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
```

Generate a **lstBookItems** item **List<>** type and add BookItem items. But first, you must create **bookItemInstance** and fill data one by one.

```
    List<BookItem> lstBookItems = new List<BookItem>();
    lstBookItems.Add(bookItemInstance);
```

After this point, if you using ASP.Net

Create a Asp:ListView or Asp:GridView using Toolbox and give data source and bind data on code behind PageLoad() method

```
    grdBooks.DataSource = lstBookItems;
    grdBooks.DataBind();
```

And now, you can change appearence this gridView as you wish at Design screen(ex: vertical).